# Arduino I2C get wrong data from slave

Tags: arduino

The code in the slave Arduino Board:

```
Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);

void requestEvent()
{
  int a = 1;
  Wire.write(a); 
}
```

The code in master Arduino Board:

```
while (Wire.available())
{
    int a = Wire.read();
    Serial.println(a);
    delay(500);
}
```

But what I see in Serial Monitor is 3 not 1.

Comment: That's a whole Wire related code? I'm missing some pretty essential stuff here to get it working. I'd recommend to use [examples from arduino.cc](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterReader) to start with. And it sends only one byte from `a`.

Comment: The problem was solved by myself.
I read the example in the Wrie library.There is a code comments **datasheet suggests at least 65 milliseconds**.So I use the function **delay()** to sleep 70ms after using the function **Wire.endTransmission()**.Then use the function **Wire.requestFrom(,)** to ask salve to transform data to master.So I get right data from slave.
Anyway,thanks [KIIV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5271927/kiiv).